# Sticky scroller changes height when it hits top of page

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I have a sticky navbar that sticks to the top of the browser window when it touches. The problem is that as soon as it touches the top the height of the navigation bar doubles. I can't seem to see what the problem is.

Here's the javascript I'm using:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){
  $(function() {
  var a = function() {
  var b = $(window).scrollTop();
  var d = $("#scroller-anchor").offset({scroll:false}).top;
  var c=$("#scroller");
  if (b>d) {
  c.css({position:"fixed",top:"0px", width:"100%",})
  } else {
  if (b<=d) {
    c.css({position:"relative",top:""})
  }
 }
};
$(window).scroll(a);a()
});
});//]]>  
</script>
```

As well as the HTML:

```
<div id="scroller-anchor"></div> 
<div id="scroller">
<div class="wrapper"> 
</div>
</div>
```

You can see the problem [here](http://www.dustinlee.co).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to remove `margin-bottom` from your `.navigation` class. Please do NOT use inline styles or !important.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. This worked perfectly. I will remove the inline CSS : )

Comment: Tim, the sticky menu you created looks awesome. Is it possible to use without var sections? The site I'm working on has sections on different pages. I tried your out but it didn't seem to work without it.

Comment: Do you mean the one on my Github? It's possible to use it without the sections on each page, but honestly there's not much of a point. Most of the code is all about highlighting the active section, scrolling to it, and highlighting the button on the menu. Without all those, you'd be better off writing a new sticky scroller from scratch. This is off topic from this thread, so email me if you need more info on that little project... my email is in the demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
#scroller {
  height:30px;  /* height of menu */
}
```

Fixes the problem.